# Using NSFont with AttributeContainer

Tags: swift, appkit, attributedstring

When creating an `AttributedString` for use in AppKit I get a warning that `NSFont` isn't `Sendable`:

```swift
    var container = AttributeContainer()
    container.appKit.foregroundColor = .red
    container.appKit.font = .systemFont(ofSize: mySize)
//  ^ Conformance of 'NSFont' to 'Sendable' is unavailable
```

The warning is correct that `NSFont` isn't `Sendable`, so is there a way to accomplish this without turning off concurrency warnings? AppKit is well behind SwiftUI and UIKit when it comes to being audited for `Sendable` conformance, but there's no much I can do about it. Marking the import of `Foundation` as `@preconcurrency` has no effect. A quick test project shows that the font is set properly and can be used in, say, an `NSTextView`. I just don't want to have to stare at those warnings until Apple gets around to AppKit refinement (historically, could be quite a while).

EDIT:
I'm using Xcode 15b5. Xcode 14.3.1 doesn't show the warning.

Comment: I don't know if this works as expected, but  `container.font = Font(NSFont.systemFont(ofSize: 12.0))` compiles without warnings.

Comment: Why am I unable to reproduce this issue? I see no warning.

Comment: Xcode 15 beta 3 produces that warning, Xcode 14 does not. (I haven't downloaded the latest Xcode 15 beta yet.)

Comment: I should have mentioned that I'm using Xcode 15b5

Comment: @smr May I suggest you mention it now, then? Edit the question...?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can initialize the container with a `[NSAttributedString.Key : Any]` dictionary. This doesn't show the warning

```
let container = AttributeContainer([.foregroundColor: Color.red, 
                                    .font: NSFont.systemFont(ofSize: mySize)])
```

Comment: You lose the type-safety, but it does work. Interestingly, it's also faster than the direct assignment method by almost 40%!

Answer (score 0):

There doesn't seem to be a great way to deal with this. I filed a feedback (FB12885931) on the issue but...you know.

There is reason to be fairly confident in marking `NSFont` as `Sendable` as it's documented in the [Cocoa Text Architecture Guide](https://developer.apple.com/library/archive/documentation/TextFonts/Conceptual/CocoaTextArchitecture/FontHandling/FontHandling.html) as follows: "Font objects are immutable, so it is safe to use them from multiple threads in your app." Hopefully Apple will audit AppKit for concurrency issues more thoroughly sometime soon.

Answer (score 0):

The following got rid of the warning for me in Xcode 15.0 beta 6:

```
    var container = AttributeContainer()
    container.appKit.foregroundColor = .red
    // Produces a value of type `AttributeScopes.SwiftUIAttributes.FontAttribute.Value`
    container.appKit.font = .init(.systemFont(ofSize: mySize))
```

Comment: Using Xcode 15 release, this doesn't compile. `AttributeScopes.SwiftUIAttributes.Value` is a typealias to `SwiftUI.Font`, but `container.appKit.font` needs an `NSFont`.

Answer (score -1):

Edited for misunderstanding:

Wrapping `NSFont` in another struct like `MainThreadFont` wouldn't eliminate the compiler warning since `NSFont` isn't declared `Sendable`. I made an oversight.

Unfortunately, as far as I know there isn't a perfect solution for this problem. For now, if you're certain about your `NSFont` usage being safe across different threads, you might need to suppress the warning using `@unchecked Sendable` attribute, but please use this sparingly and only when you're absolutely certain about thread safety, as this bypasses Swift's concurrency safety checks.

Here's an example:

```swift
struct UncheckedSendableFont: Sendable {
    @MainActor
    private let font: NSFont

    init(_ font: NSFont) {
        self.font = font
    }

    @MainActor
    var value: NSFont {
        return font
    }
}
```

Then use it like so:

```swift
var container = AttributeContainer()
container.appKit.foregroundColor = .red
container.appKit.font = UncheckedSendableFont(.systemFont(ofSize: mySize)).value
```

This will prevent the concurrency warning from appearing.

Please note that this effectively tells Swift to ignore the Sendable conformance issue for NSFont. It should only be used if you're completely confident that your usage of NSFont will not cause any concurrency issues. As a best practice, always ensure that `NSFont` instances are only accessed on the main thread, and be very careful about passing them between threads.

Comment: Doesn't that produce the same compiler warning?

Comment: ..it does... My bad. if the poster is certain about their NSFont usage being safe across different threads, they might need to suppress the warning using @unchecked Sendable attribute, but please use this sparingly and only when you're absolutely certain about thread safety, as this bypasses Swift's concurrency safety checks.

Comment: Thanks for the feedback. Seems that holding my nose and using @unchecked Sendable is the only way forward.